# Swift 2 GMSPanoramaCallback to determine if Google Street View is available

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am trying to use the method

panoViewService.requestPanoramaNearCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D: CLLocationCoordinate2D, callback: GMSPanoramaCallback)

where panoViewService = GMSPanoramaService()

to check if a Google Street View is present for a particular coordinate. I am unclear on what is returned by the callback and how I can use it to load the street view if it is present or to load an alternative view if not. I know there are similar questions already posted, but none are for Swift 2 and I don't know how to adapt the Obj-C code for Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. The following code does what I need.

```
var panoViewService = GMSPanoramaService()

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     let coord = place.position // data loaded from previous ViewController

     panoViewService.requestPanoramaNearCoordinate(coord, radius: 100) {
          GMSPanorama: GMSPanorama?, NSError: NSError?) in

         if GMSPanorama != nil {  // could have also used if NSError == nil
              // code to load my panorama view here
         } else {
             // do something else here
         }
     }
```

}